# XSLT add new node outside of current node

Tags: date, xslt, comparison, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to add a new element based on a date comparison.  If the parent DATE is within the last 7 days, I want to add a new element.  I wrote the code to do the date comparison but I'm having a hard time figuring out where to put it.  Currently, it is in the template that reformats the parent DATE but this results in my new element inside the date element.  Is there a way to create a new element outside of the current element?  Thanks.

My Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NOTICES>
    <PRESOL>
        <DATE>03012013</DATE>
        <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Interior]]></AGENCY>
        <OFFICE><![CDATA[Fish and Wildlife Service]]></OFFICE>
        <LOCATION><![CDATA[CGS-WO]]></LOCATION>
        <ZIP>97232</ZIP>
        <CHANGES>
            <MOD>
                <DATE>01112013</DATE>
                <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
            </MOD>
        </CHANGES>
     </PRESOL>
    <COMBINE>
        <DATE>03012013</DATE>
        <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Air Force]]></AGENCY>
        <OFFICE><![CDATA[Air Force Materiel Command]]></OFFICE>
        <LOCATION><![CDATA[Tinker OC-ALC - (Central Contracting)]]></LOCATION>
        <ZIP>73145-3015</ZIP>
    </COMBINE>
    <COMBINE>
        <DATE>03052013</DATE>
        <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Navy]]></AGENCY>
        <OFFICE><![CDATA[Military Sealift Command]]></OFFICE>
        <LOCATION><![CDATA[MSC Norfolk]]></LOCATION>
    </COMBINE>
    <COMBINE>
         <DATE>03292013</DATE>
         <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of Veterans Affairs]]></AGENCY>
         <OFFICE><![CDATA[Grand Junction VAMC)]]></OFFICE>
         <LOCATION><![CDATA[Veterans Affairs Medical Center]]></LOCATION>
    </COMBINE>
    <PRESOL>
        <DATE>03302013</DATE>
        <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Air Force]]></AGENCY>
        <OFFICE><![CDATA[Pacific Air Forces]]></OFFICE>
        <LOCATION><![CDATA[354 CONS - Eielson]]></LOCATION>
        <CHANGES>
             <MOD>
                 <DATE>01112013</DATE>
                 <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
             </MOD>
             <MOD>
                 <DATE>01112013</DATE>
                 <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
             </MOD>
             <MOD>
                 <DATE>01142013</DATE>
                 <COUNTRY>JAPAN</COUNTRY>
             </MOD>
         </CHANGES>
     </PRESOL>
     <FAIROPP>
         <DATE>04012013</DATE>
         <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Navy]]></AGENCY>
         <OFFICE><![CDATA[Bureau of Medicine and Surgery]]></OFFICE>
         <LOCATION><![CDATA[NH Camp Pendleton]]></LOCATION>
         <ZIP>92055</ZIP>
         <CHANGES>
             <MOD>
                  <DATE>02122011</DATE>
                  <COUNTRY>JAPAN</COUNTRY>
             </MOD>
         </CHANGES>
    </FAIROPP>
</NOTICES>
```

Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NOTICES>
    <PRESOL>
        <DATE>03012013</DATE>
        <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Interior]]></AGENCY>
        <OFFICE><![CDATA[Fish and Wildlife Service]]></OFFICE>
        <LOCATION><![CDATA[CGS-WO]]></LOCATION>
        <ZIP>97232</ZIP>
        <CHANGES>
            <MOD>
                <DATE>01112013</DATE>
                <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
            </MOD>
        </CHANGES>
     </PRESOL>
    <COMBINE>
        <DATE>03012013</DATE>
        <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Air Force]]></AGENCY>
        <OFFICE><![CDATA[Air Force Materiel Command]]></OFFICE>
        <LOCATION><![CDATA[Tinker OC-ALC  -  (Central Contracting)]]></LOCATION>
        <ZIP>73145-3015</ZIP>
    </COMBINE>
    <COMBINE>
        <DATE>03052013</DATE>
        <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Navy]]></AGENCY>
        <OFFICE><![CDATA[Military Sealift Command]]></OFFICE>
        <LOCATION><![CDATA[MSC Norfolk]]></LOCATION>
    </COMBINE>
    <COMBINE>
         <DATE>03292013</DATE>
         **<mostrecent>YES</mostrecent>**
         <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of Veterans Affairs]]></AGENCY>
         <OFFICE><![CDATA[Grand Junction VAMC)]]></OFFICE>
         <LOCATION><![CDATA[Veterans Affairs Medical Center]]></LOCATION>
    </COMBINE>
    <PRESOL>
        <DATE>03302013</DATE>
        **<mostrecent>YES</mostrecent>**
        <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Air Force]]></AGENCY>
        <OFFICE><![CDATA[Pacific Air Forces]]></OFFICE>
        <LOCATION><![CDATA[354 CONS - Eielson]]></LOCATION>
        <CHANGES>
             <MOD>
                 <DATE>01112013</DATE>
                 <COUNTRY>US</COUNTRY>
             </MOD>
             <MOD>
                 <DATE>01112013</DATE>
                 <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
             </MOD>
             <MOD>
                 <DATE>01142013</DATE>
                 <COUNTRY>JAPAN</COUNTRY>
             </MOD>
         </CHANGES>
     </PRESOL>
     <FAIROPP>
         <DATE>04012013</DATE>
         **<mostrecent>YES</mostrecent>**
         <AGENCY><![CDATA[Department of the Navy]]></AGENCY>
         <OFFICE><![CDATA[Bureau of Medicine and Surgery]]></OFFICE>
         <LOCATION><![CDATA[NH Camp Pendleton]]></LOCATION>
         <ZIP>92055</ZIP>
         <CHANGES>
             <MOD>
                  <DATE>02122011</DATE>
                  <COUNTRY>JAPAN</COUNTRY>
             </MOD>
         </CHANGES>
    </FAIROPP>
</NOTICES>
```

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="AGENCY DESC CLASSCOD CONTACT DATE NAICS LINK OFFADD OFFICE SUBJECT ZIP AGENCY ZIP"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="backdate1" select="current-date() -7*xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="backdate" select="xs:date(substring($backdate1, 1, 10))"/>
    <!-- copy all nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DATE/text()">
<!-- format DATE mm/dd/yyyy -->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 1, 2), '/', substring(., 3, 2), '/', substring(., 5, 4))"/>
    **<!-- add new node mostrecent if date is within the last 7 days -->
        <xsl:variable name="subtract_date" select="days-from-duration(xs:date(concat(substring(., 5, 4), '-', substring(., 1, 2), '-', substring(., 3, 2))) - xs:date(substring($backdate1, 1, 10)))"/>
        <xsl:if test="$subtract_date &gt;= 0">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">mostrecent</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">mostrecent</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>**
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- keep only the parent date node and delete all children date nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="DATE[../ancestor::*/DATE]"/>

    <!-- add new node type to each child node -->
    <xsl:template match="NOTICES/child::node()">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <type>
            <xsl:value-of select ="name(.)"/>
        </type>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if you match on the DATE element instead of its text node:

```
    <xsl:template match="DATE">
        <xsl:variable name="dStr" select="string(.)" />
        <xsl:variable name="bdStr" select="string($backdate1)" />
        <!-- format DATE mm/dd/yyyy -->
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($dStr, 1, 2), '/', 
                                       substring($dStr, 3, 2), '/', 
                                       substring($dStr, 5, 4))"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <!-- add new node mostrecent if date is within the last 7 days -->
        <xsl:variable name="subtract_date" 
                      select="days-from-duration(xs:date(
                                          concat(substring($dStr, 5, 4), '-', 
                                                 substring($dStr, 1, 2), '-', 
                                                 substring($dStr, 3, 2))) - 
                              xs:date(substring($bdStr, 1, 10)))"/>
        <xsl:if test="$subtract_date &gt;= 0">
          <mostrecent>YES</mostrecent>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks JL, worked great.  Question: What is it about using the text node that caused my original code not to work?

Comment: It didn't work because in your approach, the identity template was doing the job of copying the `DATE` element to the output, and then applying templates to `DATE`'s children (including the text) _inside_ that element. So anything you could have used inside that `text()` template would have been output _inside_ the `DATE` element. There's no way to get back outside it once you're in there.

Comment: I'm attempting to convert the above xslt from 1.0 to 2.0.  When I do, I receive an error: Required item type of first argument of substring() is xs:string; supplied value has item type xs:date.  What I don't understand is why this transform works in 1.0 and not in 2.0 and how to fix it.  I'm thinking that 2.0 requires more control of variable declaration.  Also, the error seems to come from my if statement because when I comment it out, the code compiles fine.

Comment: Could you try the above modification?